# How to toggle button:active when triggering a click event on that button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, click

I have a button that when pressed changes the html content of a div. I have also a jQuery function that triggers a click on that button when pressing the keyboard 'A' key.

The function works partially as I was expecting. When I press 'A' the content of the div changes but the style of the button does not change as into button:active style (when clicking directly on the button everything works fine).

I would like to have the exact same effect on key press as when clicking the button itself, **including the style change**.

*html*

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="button-state">not clicked</div>
```

*css*

```
button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button:active {
    border-color: red;
    color: red;
}
```

*js (jQuery)*

```
$(":button").click(function() {
  $("#button-state").html("button was clicked");
});

//trigger click when pressing 'A' 
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 97) {
    $(":button").trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L975nf6r/) (be sure to click on the 'Result' window to test the key press).

Answer (score 2):

The `button:active` style gets applied after the mousedown event is fired and before the actual click event happens. You can mimic the same behaviour by adding a class and removing it after some time:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 97) {
    $(":button").trigger('click');
    $("button").addClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("button").removeClass('active');
    }, 90);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xh8qsbu5/

Comment: Thanks, this does what I want, however I do not particularly like this implementation. I have up-voted your answer

Comment: I see why you don't like it, but since you can't trigger these css pseudoclasses with Javascript, something like this may be the only solution. `:active` is defined to be applied only after `:hover` and both are mouse events.